# Possible mistakes in Matrix Computations theorem 2.3.4

Tags: matrices, proof-explanation, inverse, perturbation-theory

Are the following mistakes in [Matrix Computations](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/GVL4/golubandvanloan.htm), 4th edition, Theorem 2.3.4? (page 74)

- The proof says $A + E = (I + F)A$ where $F = -EA^{-1}$, but it is easy to see that for that definition of $F$ the correct equation is $A + E = (I - F)A$.
- $r$ is defined as $||A^{-1}E||_p$ but the proof later says $||F||_p = r$ where $F = -EA^{-1}$. I am not sure why this is correct since in general $||AB||_p \ne ||BA||_p$.

Comment: I don't have that book, but both things you are pointing out are correct.

Comment: I guess, it should be $A+E = (I-F)A$.

Comment: As you can see from the [Errata](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/GVL4/Errata.htm), there are indeed some typos.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I've seen the errata, the issues I mentioned aren't there. I'll report them but wanted to make sure with better experts than me that I'm not just missing something.